# Layout wrapping logic

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to make a layout that will wrap all content through XML.

This is what I want to achieve:

my_custom_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
  layoutWidth="match_parent"
  layoutHeight="match_parent">

<view 
  id="viewTop"
  alignParentTop="true"/>

<view 
  id="viewLeft"
  alignParentLeft="true"/>

<view 
  id="viewRight"
  alignParentRight="true"/>

<view
  id="viewBottom"
  alignParentBottom="true"/>

<RelativeLayout
  id="content"
  below="viewTop"
  toRightOf="viewLeft"
  toLeftOf="viewRight"
  above="viewBottom"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I want to use this layout as root layout of all my activities/fragments.
And all have to be included at id="content" layout

activity_main.xml

```
<com.....MyCustomView
  layoutWidth="match_parent"
  layoutHeight="match_parent">

<TextView/>

<ImageView/>

...

</com.....MyCustomView>
```

What is the proper way to achieve this behavior?